# how to work with checkox in mvvm model in android

Tags: android, mvvm, checkboxlist

I am working on Recyclerview in which checkboxes are there. I want to know how to use the below to achieve MVVM data binding in android.

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:setCheckBoxListener"})
public static void setCheckBoxListener(AppCompatCheckBox checkBox, final OnCheckListener onCheckListener) {
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            onCheckListener.onCheckChanged(isChecked, (String) buttonView.getText());
        }
    });
}
```

this is the ViewModel class which I am using for the logical part. I want when I check on the checkboxes the data will be saved in the ArrayList.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codestrela.product.adapters.SelectContactAdapter;
import com.codestrela.product.data.Contact;
import com.codestrela.product.fragments.ListDialogFragment;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListDialogViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "ListDialogViewModel";
    public static final String CONTACT_LIST = "contact_list";
    public RowSelectContactViewModel viewModel;
    ListDialogFragment listDialogFragment;
    ArrayList<RowSelectContactViewModel> selectViewmodel;
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    public SelectContactAdapter adapter;

    public ListDialogViewModel(ListDialogFragment listDialogFragment) {
        this.listDialogFragment = listDialogFragment;
        adapter = new SelectContactAdapter(new ArrayList<RowSelectContactViewModel>());

        selectViewmodel = new ArrayList<>();
        onContact();
    }

    public void onContact() {
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = listDialogFragment.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(CONTACT_LIST, null);
        Toast.makeText(listDialogFragment.getActivity(), "" + json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Contact>>() {
        }.getType();
        contacts = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        Log.e(TAG, "array size: " + contacts.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            viewModel = new RowSelectContactViewModel();
            String name = contacts.get(i).getName();
            viewModel.contactName.set(name);
            viewModel.contactNumber.set(contacts.get(i).getNumber());
            Toast.makeText(listDialogFragment.getActivity(), " check "+viewModel.contactCheckbox.get(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            selectViewmodel.add(viewModel);
        }
        adapter.addAll(selectViewmodel);

    }

}
```

this is the row layout that I am using in the recycler view in the application. This checkbox is there which I am using in the application. Please help me I am very new at this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.codestrela.product.viewmodels.RowSelectContactViewModel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:checked="@{vm.contactCheckbox.get()}"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{vm.contactName}"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{vm.contactNumber}"
          android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout></LinearLayout></androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make BindingAdapter ,, it's too easy

according to [docs of two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) ,, you will just add this to your xml

it provides setting initial state of checkbox and onCheckedChange

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
    android:checked="@={viewmodel.rememberMe}"
/>
```

you have to save it to **boolean** variable

```
boolean contactCheckbox;
```

so in your xml it will be

```
 <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:checked="@={vm.contactCheckbox}"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

just add equal sign `=` .. it makes the two-way binding works

Comment: can you please elaborate on me how to use it on clicking the checkbox in the logical part.

Comment: @PrameshSingh \\ provide full code to help me know which part you want to use it in

Comment: But what about onClicklistener on pressing the checkbox

Comment: @PrameshSingh \\ everything handled with this line in xml .. try it and tell me .. it works with me

Comment: can u please tell how to do that I want to save the data of each row checkbox in ArrayList